# How to change bottom bar apps in MIUI launcher?

Tags: miui

I have installed a ROM based on MIUI. The default launcher has 4 buttons on the bottom bar; is it possible to change the app shortcut of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may Drag n drop the icons. A maximum of six is allowed

Comment: Are there any alternatives? I would like substitute the default message app but still maintain the same icon.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. You have to install the program you want and switch the icons which are stored in /data/system/customized_icons_1

Comment: If you are replacing a default app you might need to get the icon from the apk in /system/app

Comment: you can install atom launcher, it has a swipe-able bar which can hold up to 12 icons/buttons